# Uncaught Syntax: Unexpected end of input likedc.js:0

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

Several attempts which I tried to add { or ) on missing input. I've asked different question as I missed commas and brackets and also indenting wrong way. I couldn't find what is the missing { or ) in this code.

```
    Parse.Cloud.afterSave("StatusUpdate", function(request) {
  if(request.object.existed()) {
    return;
  }

  // if the user is Undefined
  var toUser = request.object.get("user") ---< **** Line 8 ****
  if (!toUser)
  {
    throw "Undefined toUser. Skipping push for Activity " + request.object.get('StatusUpdate') + " : " + request.object.id;
    return;
  }

  // put Installation query here if needed


  // send notifications based on the StatusUpdate and the passed in user from iOS ---< **** Line 16 ****
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey() // depreciated in self hosted parse servers


  // create query based on passed in values
  Parse.Cloud.define("StatusUpdate", function(request, response) {
      //query Installation for user
      var Installationquery = Parse.Object.extend("Installation");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Installationquery);
      var message = request.params.message
      query.equalTo("user", request.params.User);
      query.find({
          success: function(results) {
              response.success("found user" + results)

              // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  var object = results[i];
                  Parse.Push.send({
                              where: query, // Set our Installation query
                              data: {
                                  alert: createMessage(message),
                                  badge: "Increment", 
                                  sound: ""
                                }
                              }, {
                                  success: function() {
                                      // Push was successful
                                      console.log("sent ")
                                  },
                                  error: function(error) {
                                      console.log("Error " + error)
                                  }
                              });
              } 
          },
            error: function(error) { 
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
      });
//})
var alertMessage = function createMessage(request) {
  var message = "";

          if (request.object.get("StatusUpdate") === "likedby") {
              if (request.user.get('postedby')) {
                  message = request.user.get('postedby') + ': ' + request.object.get('statusOBJID').trim();
              } else {
                  message = "Someone liked on your status update.";
              }

              // Trim our message to 140 characters.
              if (message.length > 140) {
                  message = message.substring(0, 140);
              }

              return message;
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problems with your code:

1. Line 1: Unmatched '{'.
2. Line 7: Missing semicolon.
3. Line 18: Missing semicolon.
4. Line 26: Missing semicolon.
5. Line 30: Missing semicolon.
6. Line 45: Missing semicolon.
7. Line 48: Missing semicolon.
8. Line 76: Missing semicolon.
9. Line 76: Expected ')' and instead saw ''.
10. Line 76: Missing semicolon.

fixed:

```
 Parse.Cloud.afterSave("StatusUpdate", function(request) {
    if(request.object.existed()) {
      return;
    }
  });

  // if the user is Undefined
  var toUser = request.object.get("user");
  if (!toUser)
  {
    throw "Undefined toUser. Skipping push for Activity " + request.object.get('StatusUpdate') + " : " + request.object.id;
    return;
  }

  // put Installation query here if needed


  // send notifications based on the StatusUpdate and the passed in user from ios
  Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); // depreciated in self hosted parse servers


  // create query based on passed in values
  Parse.Cloud.define("StatusUpdate", function(request, response) {
      //query Installation for user
      var Installationquery = Parse.Object.extend("Installation");
      var query = new Parse.Query(Installationquery);
      var message = request.params.message;
      query.equalTo("user", request.params.User);
      query.find({
          success: function(results) {
              response.success("found user" + results);

              // Do something with the returned Parse.Object values
              for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                  var object = results[i];
                  Parse.Push.send({
                              where: query, // Set our Installation query
                              data: {
                                  alert: createMessage(message),
                                  badge: "Increment", 
                                  sound: ""
                                }
                              }, {
                                  success: function() {
                                      // Push was successful
                                      console.log("sent ");
                                  },
                                  error: function(error) {
                                      console.log("Error " + error);
                                  }
                              });
              } 
          },
            error: function(error) { 
                alert("Error: " + error.code + " " + error.message);
            }
        });
      });
//})
var alertMessage = function createMessage(request) {
  var message = "";

          if (request.object.get("StatusUpdate") === "likedby") {
              if (request.user.get('postedby')) {
                  message = request.user.get('postedby') + ': ' + request.object.get('statusOBJID').trim();
              } else {
                  message = "Someone liked on your status update.";
              }

              // Trim our message to 140 characters.
              if (message.length > 140) {
                  message = message.substring(0, 140);
              }

              return message;
          }
        };
```

Comment: Thanks! I received request is not defined
    at likedc.js:8:16

Comment: Indeed it helped me :) Thanks!

Comment: I am glad it helped